# Java SSLSocket::startHandshake causes inordinate delay

Tags: java, c, sockets, ssl, network-programming

We have a product, where **Client** connects to **Server**. **Client** is implemented in **C** and uses **OpenSSL**, while **Server** is implemented using **Java** code with **BufferedInputStream** and **BufferedOutputStream**. The following are my observations:

1. Application level data transfer is very slow, there is "inordinate" delay during connection establishment.
2. Using **ssldump** it was found that SSL handshake response from **Server** is taking most of the time. Rest of the application data transfer and processing hardly takes fraction of a second. The response from SSL handshake by **Server** comes after anywhere between 2 to 13 seconds after initial response sent by **Client**.
3. Subsequent analysis of the code showed that it was the first Buffered Read/Write which was taking "inordinate" amount of time.
4. Understanding that first Buffered Read/Write was hung on SSL connection completion, I introduced **SSLConnect::startHandshake()** so that I can explicitly see where is the problem. It was observed that now **startHandshake()** blocked for as much time as first Read/Write did. Further none of the Read/Write calls block, and returned data almost immediately.

I would like to understand why **startHandshake()** is taking so long. I understand that it is a asynchronous call, but still the time delay is too much IMO. Is it something to do with the socket configuration/cipher/encryption used? Using **ssldump** I found there was absolutely no data transfer between the sending of client's hello request and subsequent response from server, so apparently all the time **startHandshake()** is busy doing something or may be nothing - what I have no idea. FWIW, this is not a network latency issue, 1) all the boxes are on the same network, 2) all other data transfers combined takes less than 0.4s.

Can somebody kindly suggest what might be wrong or what can be done to fix this? Could it be some Socket or SSL setting, encryption/cipher used, or something else?

Comment: Post some relevant Java code. NB `startHandshake()` is a *synchronous* call if you call it before any I/O has been done.